# setting only the input field as empty string without the selection tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, jquery-plugins

I have a container that consists of a couple of inputs tag and one select tag. All of them have className, let's call it "contact". In jquery , I am accessing all of them through "contact". Also, there is checkbox that disables when you check it and when toy uncheck it, it empties the input fields and remove disable . The thing i want to do I want when i uncheck the checkbox, I want to set the the input fields as empty string, which i did, but what i did include the selection tag which i do not set as empty string

```js
    $("#showCheckoutHistory").change(function(event){
        if (this.checked){
          $(".contact").attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
        else {
          $(".contact").removeAttr("disabled");
          
          /* here is the problem, how can you empty the value of the                 input ONlY. Without chnaging the className Javascript and                Adding Another name in the HTML
          */
     $(".contact").val("");
        }
    });
```

```html
<input id="showCheckoutHistory" name="showCheckoutHistory" type="checkbox"/><label for="showCheckoutHistory">check</label>
    
    <div class="container">
    <input type="text" value="oo" class="form-control col-xs-10 contact"><br><br>
    <input type="text" value="xx" class="form-control col-xs-10 contact"><br><br>
      <input type="text" value="yy" class="form-control col-xs-10 contact"><br><br>

    <select class="form-control col-xs-10 contact">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option selected>C</option>
    </select>
      
    </div>
```

There is error but i dont know what is it

Comment: There is no error in your code. It looks OK to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the `$` reference in your code. That means add

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

in your html

```js
$("#showCheckoutHistory").change(function(event){
  if (this.checked){
    $(".contact").attr("disabled","disabled");
  }
  else {
    $(".contact").removeAttr("disabled");

    /* here is the problem, how can you empty the value of the                 input ONlY. Without chnaging the className Javascript and                Adding Another name in the HTML
    */
  $(".contact").each(function(i, el){
      if($(el)[0].nodeName != "SELECT"){
        $(el).val("");
      }
    });

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="showCheckoutHistory" name="showCheckoutHistory" type="checkbox"/><label for="showCheckoutHistory">check</label>

  <div class="container">
  <input type="text" value="oo" class="form-control col-xs-10 contact"><br><br>
  <input type="text" value="xx" class="form-control col-xs-10 contact"><br><br>
    <input type="text" value="yy" class="form-control col-xs-10 contact"><br><br>

  <select class="form-control col-xs-10 contact">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option selected>C</option>
  </select>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, How can i clear only the input fields WITHOUT clearing selection value when I uncheck.

Comment: @ForlanAnWest, I have changed the code. Please check... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment.
I tested your code and that works well as you want.
You missed selecting jquery in stackoverflow code snippet.
please check follow code.
If it's not working even after you added jquery script, then please let me know jquery version you used. (don't forget to add jquery cdn or picking jquery library in code snippet editor)

if you want to keep selection of select element please remove the contact class in there like below.

```js
$("#showCheckoutHistory").change(function(event){
        if (this.checked){
          $(".contact").attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
        else {
          $(".contact").removeAttr("disabled");
          
          /* here is the problem, how can you empty the value of the                 input ONlY. Without chnaging the className Javascript and                Adding Another name in the HTML
          */
     $(".contact").val("");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="showCheckoutHistory" name="showCheckoutHistory" type="checkbox"/><label for="showCheckoutHistory">check</label>
    
    <div class="container">
    <input type="text" value="oo" class="form-control col-xs-10 contact"><br><br>
    <input type="text" value="xx" class="form-control col-xs-10 contact"><br><br>
      <input type="text" value="yy" class="form-control col-xs-10 contact"><br><br>

    <select class="form-control col-xs-10"> <!-- I removed contact class in here to keep selection -->
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option selected>C</option>
    </select>
      
    </div>
```